# getting error in finding regular expression

Tags: regex, sh

I am trying to extract the regex from my file using the code

```
echo "enter file path"
read upfile
chkregex="REGEX\s+WITH\s+\/(.*)\/"
 while read line ;
do
if [[ $line =~ $chkregex ]];
then

echo "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}" >>ct.txt
fi
done<$upfile
```

like let in my file data has something like

```
REGEX WITH /^\s*COPY\s+pickled\_test\_license\s+\(id\,\s+report\_i/
```

so that regex part should be extracted.
but when i am running i get the data like

```
^s*COPYs+pickled_test_licenses+(id,s+report_i
```

Here it automatically removes \
I dont know why this happening

Answer (score 1):

`read` is stripping the backslashes from the line it reads. To prevent that, use the `-r` flag.

```
while read -r line; do
```

Your regular expression also should replace `\s` with `[[:space:]]`. Forward slashes don't have any special meaning in a regular expression, so they shouldn't need to be escaped.

```
chkregex="REGEX[[:space:]]+WITH[[:space:]]+/(.*)/"
```

Comment: my problem is not that it dont matching my line it but my problem is when it extracting the data in (.*) part it automatically escaping \ this .Like if my file contains something like \s+ it extracted as s+ ...\ is automatically removed . i dont know why

Comment: Ah, same cause, different solution. To match a literal backslash, you need to escape it.

Comment: Actually, I'm on the wrong track altogether (writing regular expressions that match regular expressions is tricky!)